# What does this error mean in Quarkus: "Model classes are defined for the default persistence unit but no default datasource found"

Tags: hibernate, quarkus

As the title says, what does this exception message actually mean?

"Model classes are defined for the default persistence unit but no default datasource found: the default EntityManagerFactory will not be created"

Quarkus build fails with this cryptic error, but tests will run happily under JUnit/Intellij.

Comment: Can you share your `application.properties` configuration file ? I suspect some issue with the way you configure the default datasource.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that in a multi-project build the correct configuration wasn't being included in a shared module. The exception message basically means that entities are present, but no configuration for oracle, or H2 etc